# Ng-repeat to compare and count objects based on value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need help to "make" NG-REPEAT and whole limitTo aware of food component ng-show logic, how can i achieve that? In other words, how can i insert that logic to ng-repeat and limiter?

JS side / HTML side? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here is what i mean in code;

```
<li 
    class="xx" 
    ng-repeat="food in foodlist.$models | filter:search:false | limitTo : foodlength as foodResults track by food.id">

    <food 
        data-food="xxx" 
        ng-show="(food.$att.random && (search.SomeBoolean || OtherBoolean)) || !food.$att.random"
        ui-sref="xx({xx: //irrelvant stuff })"
        class="xx-xxxx">
   </food>
</li>
```

Comment: Your question is not well understood my friend. What is the behaviour your are looking for?

Comment: Sorry. notice food component, there i show details of food, but based on random boolean, whether im in search mode or other boolean i show that food. What i want is to make ng-repeat and limitTo aware before hand of the same logic comparator in food ng-show. basically what happens is that i should show (example 10) foods but considering these booleans i list only 3 of them, (ng-show think its 10) how can i do the logic prior to food component logic aka MOVE it up?

Comment: @ShyAgam in short.. I always want to show 10 based on limitTo foodlength, and ng-repeat does indeed show 10 but later on my food component logic MIGHT hide few or more of them, which i dont want. I always want to show 10. So my question is how can i move that logic up, so it shows 10 no matter how many before it had to hide/remove cause they didnt satisfy ng-show logic of food component. Moving it up is my goal, any thoughts my friend?:)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to acheive this.
Your `ng-show` logic should basically move inside the `ng-repeat`.

The easiest way IMO is to add a filtering function to `$scope` in your controller, like so:

```
... // Controller creation code

function YourController($scope, ...)
{
    ... // Controller code

    $scope.filterFoodItems = function(food)
    {
        return (food.$att.random && (search.SomeBoolean || OtherBoolean)) || !food.$att.random;
    };
}
```

Next step is to change the `filter` value in your `ng-repeat`:

```html
<li 
    class="xx" 
    ng-repeat="food in foodlist.$models | filter:filterFoodItems | limitTo : foodlength as foodResults track by food.id">
...
</li>
```

Just for general knowledge, you can also write a custom filter but I don't think it's necessary in your case.
Here's how:
https://toddmotto.com/everything-about-custom-filters-in-angular-js/

Comment: Thank you man. However I have already filter:search:false which allows me to filter through based on search eg. "strawberry", is it possible to have both of them in there?

Comment: Or better yet, how can i make something that would filter:filterFoodItems or filter:search:false based on lets say random boolean.. is that possible?

Comment: if some X boolean true use filter:search:false if not use filter:filterFoodItems ... I have problems returning filter:search:false in js part   "  $scope.filterFoodItems = function(food)    {       if(booleanX) { return (food.$att.random && (s....;    } }else { return filter:search:false ; or alike.. Sorry for bothering man.

Comment: The code I gave you is just the main idea. You have to unite the logic you have in `ng-show` with the `search` variable that you have, and move it to the `filterFoodItems()` function.